# The theme system is not working for me and I'm not sure why

Tags: css, themes, vaadin, customization, vaadin-flow

Vaadin Flow newbie here.

I followed a [Youtube video on Themes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Swki9XXs9SA) and also used the starter app and I still can't get my theme going.  From what I can tell looking at  the inspector, the them doesn't appear to be loading.  Double checked the name, placement, etc.

[image: directory structure]

The contents of styles.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "LuckiestGuy";
    src: url("./fonts/Luckiest_Guy/LuckiestGuy-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "digital7";
    src: url("./fonts/digital-7/digital-7 (mono).ttf");
}
html {
    --lumo-font-family:
    --lumo-base-color: #000000;
    --lumo-primary-color: #000000;
    --lumo-primary-text-color: #ffffff;
}
body {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.page {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.logo {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3rem blue);
    width: 650px;
}
```

I've heavily edited the css file trying to get it to work, so not 100% clean.  I can't even make the background of any route/layout to be black.

Comment: At least there’s a problem in the CSS itself. The ` --lumo-font-family:` is missing the value, so at least the font is not being set, and the following base color declaration is also going to be discarded because of that.

Comment: Yeah, I was in the middle of editing when I decided to post this.  Probably should have removed all the unused/testing stuff, such as the one missing the value. Sorry about that.  Not a good post.  Will do better next time.

Comment: I also noticed you used `text-color`, which is not a CSS property. Use `color` instead.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are either missing the `@Theme` annotation in Java, or you are not importing the extra CSS files from within `styles.css`.

To enable the custom-theme mechanism you need to ensure that you have the `@Theme("my-theme-name")` annotation on a class that implements AppShellConfigurator. For example, in a Spring Boot application, you could have an application configuration class such as the following:

```java
@Theme("my-theme-name")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
                         implements AppShellConfigurator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then (assuming you are not styling something in the shadow DOM of components) you can place your styling either in:

1. `frontend/themes/my-theme-name/styles.css` directly
2. Or in another CSS file that is imported from withing `styles.css`. For example, if you have styles inside `frontend/themes/my-theme-name/fonts/my-fonts.css`, then you should add the following line inside `styles.css`:

```css
@import url('./fonts/my-fonts.css');
```

Check this [guide](https://foojay.io/today/how-to-style-a-vaadin-application/) for more info on styling Vaadin using CSS.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do have @Theme in my application class.  Same name as theme, of course.

Comment: What I don't see is any evidence of the theme styles.css being loaded.  I've added a class, page, to the view, as an example and when I inspect the page, I see the class property being added. But then I filter for "page" in the inspector under Styles, page does not show up. This leads me to believe styles.css is not being loaded for some reason.  

In the page...
<vaadin-vertical-layout class="page" theme="padding" style="width: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100%; text-align: center;"> ...

In my Applicaton: 

@Theme("upnext")

Comment: I'm not sure where in the inspector one should find evidence that the CSS is being loaded. But the sure-fire way is to add `* {color:red;}` to styles.css and see if anything changes.

Comment: Filtering for "page" in the inspector "Styles" panel will only show something if you have an element selected that has that class applied. So make sure you have the "page" element selected.